# Changing controller property values

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember.js, what are the best practises for modifying a controller's property values?

Consider the following toy application:

**JS:**

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    firstNameBinding: "App.myModel.name",
    lastName: "Smith",
    signedIn: true
});

App.myModel = Ember.Object.create({
    name: 'John'
});
```

**HB:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{#if signedIn}}
        Welcome back, <b>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</b>!
    {{else}}
        Welcome, <b>Guest</b>!
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

I am capable of changing the value of `firstName` by running `App.myModel.set('name', 'Jane')`. But I'm having a hard time changing the value of `lastName`.

How can I modify `lastName` in real-time? Moreover, where is the instance of `App.ApplicationController` stored in the DOM?

Comment: I don't thing anything is stored in the DOM when using Ember. You should read the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/), specifically about Ember conventions. You're mixing things in a way that is looking problematic: Your `lastName` is a string and your `firstName` is a binding observing another property in another object (in a way that's not really recommended). You should pass instances of your models to their controllers' content property (preferably via routing) instead of creating properties in the controller that are already represented in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you attempting to modify the property of a controller from your model? Because that's very much against the way MVC works. [Your controller should be modifying your view](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/MVC-Process.png). So in this case your `lastName` property should be stored in your model, rather than on the controller.

Since you're binding straight to a property in the model, you have don't have access to the model per-se. The best way is to bind to the object, and then you have access to all of its properties:

`firstNameBinding: "App.myModel"`

And then we can change all of the properties on `App.myModel` from the controller (`this.set('firstName.someRandomProperty', 'Adam');`).

`ApplicationController` is an object, and therefore won't be stored in the DOM. Ember uses the [concept of a factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for providing access to objects. For example, to get the `ApplicationController` instance we can use the following, although it's inadvisable unless you're really sure you need it, because instances are accessible in more logical ways:

```
this.container.lookup('controller:application')
```